# Sql filter query with join objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have two tables:

```
Foo:
Foo_no | Bar_no | props1 | props2
(Relationship in the model)
Bar_no = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bar.Bar_no'))
bar = db.relationship('Bar', foreign_keys=Bar_no)

Bar:
Bar_no | status | props3 | props4
```

I'm trying to do a query with sqlalchemy to find any rows in **Foo** that contains a specific status in **Bar**

This is what I have so far to join it

```
query = Foo.query

if 'status' in filters:
    query.join(Bar)
    query = query.filter(Foo.bar.status == filters['status'])

return query
```

I'm not too sure how to create the query to filter from these two tables to filter out the correct status that Foo has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of ways. Simple:

```
Foo.query.join(Bar).filter_by(Bar.status == filters['status']).all()
```

More explicit:

```
Foo.query.join(Bar, Foo.bar_no == Bar.bar_no).filter(Bar.status == filters['status']).all()
```

With join condition:

```
Foo.query.join(Bar, and_(Foo.bar_no == Bar.bar_no, Bar.status == filters['status'])).all()
```

Through session, if you only need selected list of columns in result:

```
db.session.query(Foo.Foo_no, Foo.props1).join(Bar, Foo.bar_no == Bar.bar_no).filter(Bar.status == filters['status']).all()
```

Ofc, there is more ways and you always can find that fit your needs.